# How to install pymssql module in Python 3.8?

Tags: python, pip

when i run this command
pip install pymssql in windows in virtualenv for python 3.8
i get this error:
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

how can i install pymssql in windows.

Comment: There's still a lot of modules not compatible with 3.8, I've heard a lot of people are sticking to 3.7 for a while

Comment: I was able to install using github repo.  1) Download repo https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql 2) unzip it and cd into it 3) install freetds-devel (ex: yum install freetds-devel)  4) run python3.8 ./setup.exe install

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pymssql is still not compatible with Python 3.8, please see the pr here: https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/pull/659

Answer (score 2):

You can use this library https://pypi.org/project/pymssql-linux/ which is a fork of `pymssql` which is not maintained anymore (https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/668):

```
pip install pymssql-linux
```

For windows you can download relevant `whl` from:

[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pymssql](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pymssql) and then

`pip install path-to-your-downloaded-whl-file`